# Sql query between two dates with textboxes

Tags: c#, sql, database, gridview, textbox

I have a query that gets data from my database and it needs to filter out data between certain dates that the user will fill in two textboxes.
I need to fill in the textboxes like: 2016-9-13 otherwise it wont work (the date in the database is also 2016-9-13).
But when it fills the gridview the cell says: 13-9-2016.

I want to fill in the dates in the order like: 13-9-2016. How can i do this and what do i need to change?

Here is some code that gives me the data from the database.

```
 connect = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LP12;Initial Catalog=Data;Integrated Security=True");
        connect.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = connect;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DrukSensor, FlowSensor, TempSensor, KwaliteitSensor, OlieVerbruik, Toerental, DateTime, Schip FROM SysteemSensorInfo WHERE DateTime BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", TextBoxBeginDatum.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", TextBoxEindDatum.Text);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Never use AddWithValue passing it strings if you want to query dates

Comment: Also consider to use a DateTimePicker to get the date input from your users so they cannot claim that they mean "01/02/2016" to be two of january instead of first of february.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, parse the dates and pass down `DateTime` values:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", ParseDate(TextBoxBeginDatum.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", ParseDate(TextBoxEindDatum.Text));

...

static DateTime ParseDate(string text) {
    // TODO; possibly just: return DateTime.Parse(text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use Datediff() function. Internally, It will manage valid date in any format for dates comparison.

```
"SELECT DrukSensor, FlowSensor, TempSensor, KwaliteitSensor, OlieVerbruik,     Toerental, DateTime, Schip 
FROM SysteemSensorInfo 
WHERE datediff(day,DateTime,@StartDate)<=0 AND datediff(day,DateTime,@EndDate)>=0"
```